# Find directory name with wildcard or similar to "like"

Tags: unix, directory

I am using the following command to find a directory name.

```
 find / -type d -name "ora10"
```

My problem is, I am not sure what the exact directory name is, so I would like to find directories similar to `"ora10g"`, `"ora10client"`, etc.

How can I do this with find?

Comment: Maybe `"ora10*"`?

Comment: @Coodey that is most likely correct and should be an answer.

Comment: @Coodey you should have posted this answer...you got it right first.

Answer (score 185):

find supports wildcard matches, just add a `*`:

```
find / -type d -name "ora10*"
```

Comment: Without quotes, remember to escape the asterisk: `find / -type d -name ora10\* -print`